# JAVA - При изменении цвета меняется размер элемента

Tags: java, android

Проблема заключается, что при смене цвета кнопки происходит то ли смещение, то ли изменение стиля, как проверить и исправить, и почему цвет так дурно влияет?

---

```
if(countChose > 0) {         
    butCreate.setText(getString(R.string.b_delete));                        
    butCreate.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryRed));
    butCreate.setId(R.id.b_delete);
} else {                        
    butCreate.setText(getString(R.string.b_create));                           
    butCreate.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    butCreate.setId(R.id.b_add);
}
```

[image: https://sun9-68.userapi.com/c858224/v858224671/1a7ded/3fDZGGzDgA0.jpg]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не нужно менять ID кнопки, это статический параметр на всю работу приложения (как, например,  ваша фамилия) и его изменение создаст только проблемы и костыли в работе. если вам нужно как то идентифицировать изменение кнопки, то у View есть методы getTag() и setTag(), в которые вы можете поместить и считать, соответственно, любую сущность: примитивы или объекты. в вашем случае подошло бы хранить булевую переменную (false - удаление, true - добавление) - это позволит проще организовать логику операторов if, например

Answer (score 2):

Из того что я вижу на вашей картинке к зеленым кнопкам применен drawable файл со стилем кнопки. Этот самый drawable задается параметром setBackground() (скорее всего в вашем случае в XML разметке). А потом вы в коде меняете этот параметр background на простую заливку цветом, вот в этом ваша и проблема.

Решение в том, чтоб либо для другого цвета создать второй drawable с другим цветом и тем же параметрами и применить его вместо цвета. Можно еще попробовать такое решение

```
Drawable unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_drawable); 
Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, Color.RED);
```

Comment: Я использую стандартные кнопки, с стилем: 
@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored
background @android:drawable/btn_colored_material
Я посмотрел и хотел найти этот стиль,чтобы обратится к нему и поменять цвет, но я не нашел.
Есть ли возможность изменить стиль или найти его исходник?

Comment: Вам нужно писать свой стиль. Стили которые вам представляет система вы менять не можете